# What is the standard way to create and open files in Android?

Tags: android, c++, file, filesystems, android-file

We want to create/open a file from a file path, or when a user specifies a particular location for file creation from the UI.

We want to support operations like create file if it doesn't exist, open file and fail if it doesn't exist, open file and create if doesn't exist. Similar to what the Linux `open()` call provides.

We also want to be able to open the file in different modes such as read only and read write.

While we could use the Linux `open()` call itself in the C++ code, when the user selects a file or directory from the UI, we get a Uri and not the actual path of the file. In this case the open() call doesn't work.

We tried `open()` in the code from C++ but it didn't work with Uri.
We also tried `ParcelFileDescriptor` it does work with paths (prefixed with `file://`) as well as Uri but doesn't provide all the desired modes of open and create.

Comment: Which method you can use depends on the path where the file should be created. In the app-internal directories you can use standard `open` command.